# How can i print something on the serial monitor only once

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a button connect to my arduino board and i want the serial monitor to display pressed when the button is pressed and released when the button is not pressed.
My problem is that i want it to be print only once but with my code it prints it non stop.
I already tried writing the code in void setup but i cant seem to make it work.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
I would really appreciate the help.

```
const int pinButton = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton);
  if(stateButton == 1) {
     Serial.println("PRESSED"); 
  } else {
     Serial.println("RELEASED"); 
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: Get the state _change_ and remember whether it has been printed already. Global variables ( defined outside loop() ) keep their value from one loop round to later ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my first answer on stack overflow.
Anyway, the solution I suggest is to save previous state of the button in another variable, compare it to the new state, if they are diffrent you print the message, else you don't.
Here's a code example :

```
const int pinButton = 8;
int previous_state;

void setup() {
   pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   previous_state = digitalRead(pinButton);
}

void loop() {
    int new_state = digitalRead(pinButton);
    if(new_state == 1 && previous_state==0) {
       Serial.println("PRESSED"); 
    } if(new_state == 0 && previous_state==1) {
       Serial.println("RELEASED"); 
    }
    previous_state=new_state;
    delay(20);
}
```

This is not the optimal solution, but it should work. Chek out interruptions on Arduino to see how to do it better.